# Distance between a point and the sublevel set of a convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let  $f(x) : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex and differentiable function, and let $P$ be a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Define a function $g(m): R \rightarrow R$ to be the distance between point $P$ and the sub-level set $ K_m = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid f(x) \le m\}$, i.e., $g(m) = d(P, K_m)$. Is the function $g$ a continuous function? If not, is there any restriction on $f$ that will make $g$ continuous? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to use the characterization $d(P, K_m) = \inf_{x: f(x) \le m} d(x, P)$ and tried to show that for all $x$, $\epsilon>0$, there exist some $\delta >0$, such that $|d(P, K_m) - d(P, K_{m+\delta})| \le \epsilon$, but it didn't get me anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: the function $g$ is convex.

Indeed, we have

$$\lambda_1 K_{m_1} + \lambda_2 K_{m_2} \subset K_{\lambda_1 m_1 + \lambda_2 m_2}$$ since $f$ is convex, and

$$d(P, \lambda_1 K_{m_1} + \lambda_2 K_{m_2}) \le \lambda_1 d( P, K_{m_1}) + \lambda_2 d(P, K_{m_2} ) $$ since $Q\mapsto d(P, Q)$ is convex.

Comment: Thanks! However, I do not fully understand why the function $Q \rightarrow d(P,Q)$ is convex when $Q$ is a convex set. Is there any reference I can look at?

Comment: I see. We can set $x \in \lambda_1 K_{m_1}$ and $y \in \lambda_2 K_{m_2}$ such that $d(P, \lambda_1 K_{m_1}) = d(P, x)$ and $d(P, \lambda_2 K_{m_2}) = d(P,y)$, and use triangle inequality. Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at this is note that $ h(x, \lambda, m) = d(x, P) + \lambda (f(x) - m)$ is an affine function of $m$ and a convex function for $x$, for each given $\lambda$.

Hence $h_1(x, \lambda) = max_{\lambda \ge 0} h(x, \lambda, m)$ is a convex function of $m$ and $x$ since point-wise supremum preserves convexity, and $g(m) = \min_x h_1(x,m)$ is convex in $m$ since minimization preserves convexity.

Comment: Minimization does not preserve convexity. For example, x and -x are convex on the line but their minimum is not.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I am using the result that if $f$ is convex in $(x,y)$ and $C$ is convex and nonempty, then $g(x) = \inf_{y \in C} f(x,y)$ is convex provided $g(x) >-\infty$ for all $x$. This can be found in the textbook by Boyd and Vandenberghe Chapter 3 section 3.25. https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf